# Stunning GUI: How is it technically done

Tags: user-interface, cross-platform

This question is somewhat related to another one already posted about graphical user design.
([Learning to create beautiful /next-generation GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713302/learning-to-create-beautiful-next-generation-gui))

I've read a lot about UI design by now. While still being far away from being experienced, I now know about some caveats to look at. But my concern isn't the design guidelines.

It's rather that I'd like to know how this is done technically. Like ShaChris23 in the SO question, I'm tired of writing "plain old looking" GTK/Windows GUI.

Let's take some concrete examples:

- http://dribbble.com/shots/1130346-iPhone-Mobile-Design-Concept
  Do you see that component in the 3/4 of the page which is looking like a time line? Is there a component doing this? Do you lay out the individual buttons by hand? No way.
- [Springseed](http://getspringseed.com/) as well is a good example. In my opinion, it has a stunning yet simple UI. It looks nice, clean and simple.
- Last example: http://dribbble.com/shots/1145034-Outdoors-ui-free-PSD - I know this is a PSD which may or may not have been realized in software.

My question is not about these very concrete examples. But let's say you have designed your GUI in Photoshop. And now? How are you going to realize it technically from this point on? Do you write custom components for the toolkit you're using? Do you reinvent the wheel then for different platforms where you have no common toolkit? (Apple iOS vs Android).

Not talking about web technologies, but real apps.

By the way: I heard about WPF and stuff. I'm developing for Java, C++ and some C# if required. But I'm looking for a cross-platform way.

Any tip is appreciated

Comment: Interesting, Do you want me to suggest a UI frameworks ? Or you are asking me "How to create UI frameworks " ? Please clear me what you are exactly want.

Comment: Use [tag:node.js]. `npm install phaser` and set it to stun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised this question hasn't been closed for being to broad, as it's a bit hard to discern what you're really asking. But if you're asking for **a cross-platform framework that enables you to implement stunning UI designs**, have a look at [kivy](http://kivy.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Let's discuss the first item, the timeline control.

It would be a series of custom views, one for a callout (1 triangle and a rectangle button with text on it), a timeline (a single line and array of dots), and a wrapping view that would accept a list of names to plot on the timeline.

Each view would be responsible for drawing itself. The view could use spliced images from a psd, or actually draw itself. As far as trying to develop cross-platform code, it can be done, but that usually means that you'll have to accept a number of compromises on each platform.

As an alternative, you could use html5 views for your interface, with native code to wire up the business logic.

Here is a rough example of creating the callouts using a javascript canvas. 
http://jsfiddle.net/5ZMn9/7/

```
function Callout() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 0;
    this.height = 0;
    this.position = 1;
    this.name = "";
}
Callout.prototype = {
    draw: function(canvas) {
       var callout = this;
       canvas.drawPolygon({
          fillStyle: 'blue',
          x: callout.x, y: callout.y-12+callout.position*25,
          radius: 5,
          sides: 3,
          rotate: (callout.position)*180
        });
        canvas.drawRect({
          fillStyle: 'blue',
          x: callout.x, y: callout.y,
          width: 50,
          height: 20
        });
        canvas.drawText({
          fillStyle: '#fff',
          x: callout.x, y: callout.y+2,
          fontSize: 8,
          fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
          text: callout.name            
        });
    }
};

function Timeline() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.length = 0;
    this.stops = 0;
}
Timeline.prototype = {
    draw: function(canvas) {
        var timeline = this;
        canvas.drawLine({
          strokeStyle: '#960',
          strokeWidth: 2,
          x1: timeline.x, y1: timeline.y,
          x2: timeline.x+timeline.length, y2: timeline.y
        });
        for ( var i=0; i < this.stops; i++) {
            canvas.drawEllipse({
              fillStyle: '#c90',
              x: timeline.x+30+50*i, y: timeline.y,
              width: 8, height: 8
            });
        }
    }
};

function Wrapper() {
    this.names = [];
    this.height = 300;
    this.width = 600;
}
Wrapper.prototype = {
    draw: function(canvas) {
        $(canvas).clearCanvas();
        var timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.x = 0;
        timeline.y = 45;
        timeline.length = this.names.length*50+10;
        timeline.stops = this.names.length;
        timeline.draw(canvas);
        for ( var i = 0; i<this.names.length; i++) {
           var callout = new Callout();
           callout.x = i*50+30;
           callout.y = i%2*50+20;
           callout.position = 1-i%2;
           callout.name = this.names[i];
           callout.width=90;
           callout.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
};

var wrapper = new Wrapper();
wrapper.names = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five"];
wrapper.draw($('canvas'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing for multiple platforms with no common toolkit you should probably be developing different UIs for each platform.

In the case of iOS/Android, each platform has different style guides. In addition, their native API's are designed specifically to support apps developed with those guides - if you try to build a new GUI from scratch (say, using your own OpenGL based widget toolkit), it won't matter how 'cool' it looks. Even if you consider it to be intuitive and easy to use, the odds are that it will be counter-intuitive for users accustomed to the conventions of the host platform, as they haven't had time to become familiar with your custom UI yet.

In the iPhone example you've given, yes, the buttons would be laid out manually. Sort of. They're probably relying on Cocoa's AutoLayout system rather than statically positioning each element.

That being said, there's probably no need to 'invent the wheel' each time. There are a large number of UI components (on iOS at least) that have been developed by the community - for examples, take a look at [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) (specifially, I've used [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) before to get a cover flow-like effect).